# Design and develop A/b split email campaign tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, database-design

I'm working on developing a tool which is quite similar to A/B split email campaign tools available in market. I would need some pointers/suggestion about design aspect. Main aspect is database design. I'm not expecting a solution here but just an approach.

Any help on database design, design patterns, best approach, third party plug-ins would be appreciated.

P.S. I'm using ROR and PostgreSql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some concepts I would want to represent as database structures:

1. An email. Simple, but if has to be there. I would store both A/B versions in the same table.
2. Probably a user. I assume you will be implementing some kind of feature that sends a 1x1 pixel image and then recording the IP/email address that loaded the image. You want to store that in a table.
3. It happens a lot - users send an email, realize an error and send it again. You'll need to think about storing historical versions of emails and their activity. "Email ID 123 got sent once on Monday and again on Tuesday." Don't combine those stats, make sure they are separate.
4. You're going to be doing a lot of comparing. The queries might be expensive to run against successful campaigns. Might be a good idea to do some pre-processing of stats in a table.
5. You'll need a campaign to track emails and their A/B behavior. Make a campaign table to group the emails activity/results.

When designing a database, I like to find the most central object and design around that. In this case I would nominate campaign or email. Make one the sun in your universe that everything else revolves around and that will help you design the rest.